# I need a SubSonic 2.0.3 - SubCommander exe

Tags: subsonic, data-access-layer

I am trying to make changes to a site that uses SubSonic 2.0.3. I have all of the code but I need to regenerate some database tables. I do not have the SubCommander exe though. I looked for an archive location but I can not find it.

Is there a way to get the SubCommander of this version. I really don't have the time to change every page to use the latest version.

-thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you still have a copy of the *.aspx template files, newer builds from SubSonic 2 should do the same work for you since subcommander just takes the templates and generates some classes.

You can grab SubSonic 2.1 from here: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0/downloads

You should give it a try.

If you can't find the templates you could use a resource editor like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/asmex.aspx and extract them since they are part of the subsonic.dll

Answer (score 0):

A bit late - but if you still need it -> https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5853240/SubSonic%202.0.3.zip